# Is a class an instance of an object?

Tags: java

Is a class an instance of an object?
Can you create many objects from the same class, and can a class have many instances?

Thank you for your help, I'm reading a book on Java programming and am currently confused about these definitions.

Comment: In java [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) is also a class.

Comment: It's the complete opposite. An object is an instance of a class.

Answer (score 6):

A "class" conceptually is not an object (or an "instance of an object", which makes no sense really), but rather a sort of blueprint from which objects are created. Objects are *instances* of classes. You can indeed instantiate a class many times.

Don't confuse this with instances of the `Class` class, which are objects (e.g. `String.class`, `int.class` etc.).

Comment: So is an object is an instance of a class.

Comment: So, technically speaking, it would be incorrect to say that a class is a instance of an object

Comment: @dadoo It would be completely incorrect. An object is an instance of a class.

Comment: Dang I have no idea how I had the concepts mixed up

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Stupid misunderstanding ! @arshajii

Comment: Sometimes it helps clarify the discussion to talk about Big-C Classes and little-c classes.  Let "little-c class" mean the conceptual "sort of blueprint from which objects are created", and let "Big-C Class" mean an instance of the java.lang.Class class---a concrete Java object that embodies the "sort-of-blueprint" concept.

Answer (score 1):

A class describes the structure of an object and is not an instance.
An instance is an object that conforms to the structure defined by the class.
There can be many instances of a class.

For example, consider a "Person" class. When creating the class, you could say, "A person may have a first name or a last name," but you're not creating an actual person, you're just saying what makes up a person. When you create a person, you create an instance of the class "Person" and you may have many people, which means having many instances of the class "Person".

Comment: A class _is_ an instance.  It is an instance of the Class class, and since Class extends Object, a class _is_ an object.

Comment: @jameslarge Wrong. A `Class` object, is an object of type `Class`, but this just applies to java, as the java API does have a `Class` class. The question itself is a general OOP question. Technically speaking, an object is an instance of a class. This answer is right.

Comment: I don't believe that is what he is asking. I believe he is asking the question about the conceptual definition of a class versus an instance and happened to mention Java.

Comment: Thanks, @BackSlash. Would you vote this answer back up?

Comment: "The question itself is a general OOP question"  Maybe so, but it's tagged with "java", and it says, "I'm reading a book on Java programming and am currently confused about..."

Comment: A very clear and detailed answer with a very good example and easy to understand, thank you @allen1

Answer (score 0):

The CLASS works as a BLUEPRINT which allows you to create OBJECTS based on this BLUEPRINT.
You CAN create many instances (OBJECTS) of the same CLASS.

To clarify:

> Object - Objects have states and behaviors. Example: A dog has states
>   - color, name, breed as well as behaviors -wagging, barking, eating. An object is an instance of a class.
>
> Class - A class can be defined as a template/blue print that describes
>   the behaviors/states that object of its type support.

Answer (score 0):

A class is not an instance of an object. In fact, an object is an instance of a class. Here is the explanation,

Conceptually, each class represents and describes the characteristics of an independent concept in a program. these characteristics are also owned by any object of this class type. Usually, instance variables of a class defines properties of an entity. For example, if you have a class called Student, then obviously this class should have instance variables that represents student's characteristics such as name, level, grade...etc. Also, it can have methods like getGrade (), getName (). Now, any object of type Student will have the properties defined by its class (eg. name, level..), meaning the information stated in the class is encapsulated in its objects. Also, this object can be used to reach for the methods like getGrade or getName (again because these methods are encapsulated inside each object).

The class is the definition of a single concept structure, and the object is an implementation of this structure. That's why, we say, an object is an instance of a class. Note that we can have various instances (objects) of a single class, each object will encapsulate the same structure defined by its class, but with different values. For example, you may have several objects of the class Student each represents a different student with different name, level, grade...etc. Although these objects are different, they share the same structure, meaning they are all students.

Data encapsulation provided by class/object technique is really useful. Suppose you have 100 students who you need to store their names, levels, and any other related information. Instead of defining 100 String variables to store each student name, and 100 int variables to store the levels, you simply create a class which defines a student structure and create as many objects as you want. It saves both time and effort, and it makes debugging much easier.